# Azure NPM Issue: msnodesql Fails to deploy

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to set up msnodesql (formerly node-sqlserver) with my azure hosted site and am running into some issues.

Essentially I'm getting a deployment failed within Azure. I believe it is due to the fact NPM is trying to install msnodesql on the server but will fail because it would need "node-gyp", Python and C++ 2010 installed (which is not present on the azure side).  Here is the error message I'm seeing

```
npm ERR! msnodesql@0.2.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the msnodesql@0.2.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the msnodesql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls msnodesql
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've been hacking at this error for a while now and nothing seems to fix it.  The best answer I've gotten is to manually include the msnodesql within node_modules (as specified by http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2012/11/16/install-npm-packages-automatically-for-node.js-on-windows-azure-web.aspx ).  I feel like that should fix it but alas it does not.  I also tried compiling it against the local x86 node and also just using a prebuilt x86 one (suggested by http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2012/09/18/node.js-adventure---when-node.js-meets-windows-azure.aspx ).

Any other suggestions would be appreciated here.

Also worth noting is it's working in my local environment just fine and can grab data in from the SQL Azure DB I created (once i've whitelisted my IP) using msnodesql running within webmatrix but hitting Azure SQL DB.

I originally had an issue with the DB and the Website in Azure being on different regions, but I corrected that.

Answer (score 5):

As Glenn Block mentioned, the problem stems from Azure tyring to build the native module when you deploy. This can happen for a few reasons, maybe you didn't upload the binary, maybe it's the wrong binary, or maybe the deployment directory got screwed up.

The Azure server wants the 32 bit driver for Node .6.

What I had to do was FTP into my azure server and delete everything in /site/wwwroot/ except for web.config. You can probably get away with just deleting node_modules, but because the behavior was unexpected I wanted to clean out everything.

Then I went into my Node project directory on my local machine, and went into the node_module/msnodesql directory and deleted everything but package.json and lib directory. In the lib directory, I created separate directories for the binary for my dev machine(64 bit .8) and azure, called 64 and 32 respectively.

I then modified, sqlserver.native.js as follows

```
try {
    module.exports = require('./32/sqlserver.node'); //Azure version
}
catch (e) {
    try {
        module.exports = require('./64/sqlserver.node'); //My local machine
    }
    catch (e) {
        try {
            module.exports = require('../build/Release/sqlserver.node');
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.error('Native sqlserver module not found. Did you remember to run node-gyp configure build?');
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

The big point to make here is that, we try to load all available versions to accommodate for every possibility of deployment I might have, but give priority to the Azure server. On my local dev machine, we failed to load the node from /32 since it's the wrong format, and we fall back to /64.

I bet if I put a little bit of effort into this, I could easily trim what gets deleted down to the bare minimum, but after wasting hours upon hours resolving this, I had enough.

Comment: Thank you!!! Banged my head against the wall for hours on this one. I didn't have the 32/64-bit compatibility issue, but I still got the same error. I cleaned out my node_modules/msnodesql directory leaving only package.json, lib directory and build directory, and then it finally worked.

Comment: Cleaning the msnodesql directory and blowing away all but web.config in wwwroot worked!  Thank you!

Comment: There is a bunch of work going on to improve the general native module story for Windows. It should be hitting the streets soon. Sorry you guys had so much trouble :-(

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is because it is trying to build the native module when you deploy. We don't support *building* native modules in Windows Azure Websites. You can however deploy the binary and then it will work but you would need to not have it in your package.json. Follow this post for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/06/08/introducing-the-microsoft-driver-for-node-js-for-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Makes sense.  I think I was going down another route before.  I got the not having it within the package.json part I think but strugged with how to get it included in my environment.  Good to know thats the route to follow, pretty sure this will solve my problem.

Comment: I think I must not have something configured within my package.json.  It still tries to deploy within NPM although I dont have it included in my package.json and instead just have the msnodesql folder within my node_modules for my site.

Comment: Here's my package.json:  `{
  "name": "Lisn",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "./server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*",
    "jade": "~0.22.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.6.14"
  }
}`

Comment: I'm just saying that since you're program manager to bring node.js to Azure you should know. I'm a paying costumer and I expected this to be a lot more straightforward. Connecting node to sql azure should be simple and intuitive.

Comment: That does not work. The most irritating part here is that msnodesql seems to be created by MS team and is not working with another MS projec despite all Azure tutorials and guides...

Comment: @GlennBlock - can you please elaborate in a way that provides specific instructions for how to address the issue, particularly for those of us who are new to developing in Node.js? That is, WHY is it trying to build the native module and how do we get it to stop? Do we need to remove the package.json file from node_modules/msnodesql directory? By "the binary" do you mean sqlserver.node? Do we need to remove everything but the sqlserver.node file? Please advise.

Comment: A year later this is still an issue :/ Kind of disappointing to find my own comment from a year ago and see it has not progressed since.